# iOS passing an Image to an IBOutlet of another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have ClassA 
and subclass ClassB

Is it possible to pass an image from the UIImage picker from ClassA to ClassB

```
NSLog(@"Camera Dismiss Method Reached");
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
ClassB.patientImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

where "patientImage" is a UIViewController (IBOutlet) property of ClassB

and here is the property for Patient Image, in ClassB.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *patientImage;
```

doing it this way however gives me an error "patientImage" not found on object type

Your help is very appreciated

Comment: So have you declared a property for patientImage in ClassB.h?

Comment: I have and Edited my question to address this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objects are usually created using this method:

```
ClassB myClassBObject=[ClassB alloc]init];
```

and later you can access to patientImage

```
myClassBObject.patientImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

I hope it's will be work

Comment: your absolutely right  . . . I forgot completely ! ! ! !
Thank you !